# Tortoise SVN checkout via LAN

Tags: tortoisesvn, lan

I have recently installed Tortoise SVN on Windows and have two computers, A and B. On both machines I installed TortoiseSVN and they are connected Via LAN and I have my repository saved in computer A. I want to access/checkout the repository in Computer A from Computer B, so i tried this URL in the repository to SVNcheckout from Computer B,

```
http://192.168.2.6/Repository
```

but i got a error message as,

```
repository moved permanently to 'http://192.168.2.6/Repository'; please relocate
```

tried some other URL's as well like,

```
http://192.168.2.6/C:/wamp/www/Repository/
http://192.168.2.6///C:/wamp/www/Repository/
file:///192.168.2.6///C:/wamp/www/Repository/
```

but got error messages as,

```
access to 'http://192.168.2.6/C:/wamp/www/Repository/'; forbidden
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-301-error and http://serverfault.com/questions/256993/svn-error-when-commiting-access-denied-foobar-mkactivity-myrepo could help here?

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution myself, I didnt actually have a SVN server installed, with which i could retrieve the repository through a specific URL from  other computer. I installed [VisualSvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) and that solved the problem..

Comment: Mind sharing which of your above URLs ended up working?

Answer (score 1):

It is able to do that on LAN.
1. Remember to share the folder you use as repository
2. On pc B, select SVN checkout..., click the browse button, locate to that shared folder.

And it's done.

Comment: Now that you have enough rep, you could add a screenshot!

Comment: The manual says explicitly to never do this. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html